# SVN Repo works without authentication

Tags: authentication, svn, repository, svn-repository

I have created SVN host using:

```
<Location /svn>
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/Main_Folder/company-1
     AuthType Basic
     SVNListParentPath On

     AuthName "Test"

     <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require valid-user
     </LimitExcept>
  </Location>`
```

Although I have specified user privileges in svnserve.conf, it does not seem to "take it" because I can access the repository (see below) without any prompt for user/password.

[image]

Can you please point what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs, it seems that you use a wrong configuration file.

Configuration settings in the file [`svnserve.conf`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.ref) do not have any effect in this particular case. Your [server runs Apache](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) and Apache does not process `svnserve.conf`. This configuration file is used by [`svnserve` custom server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) only.

Comment: I am able to have this setup so that it ask me username/password for SVN. Now how can I have it ask me username/password for HTTP? Please let me know.